# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use `Bootstrap 3 Datepicker` in Visual Studio but it does not respond. When i am clicking on `<input type='text' class="form-control" />` calendar do not appear. What i missed?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'ru'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

After adding all that was said before it's became better but still do not work

Was:

[image]

Now:
[image]

In Console i found error `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function"`

Comment: Do not include both the minified and non-minified versions of scripts (`bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` and `bootstrap.js`) And move `bootstrap.js` before `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`. And the `id='datetimepicker1`  should be applied to the input, not the `div`

Comment: if there is a .css file for datetimepicker then don't forget to add it before the  .js file

Comment: @Mir, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup do not contain any css in examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh I see. The problem lies in the order of your files included and also few requirements are missing. And just to confirm - Yes, you do require the CSS of Bootstrap as well as Bootstrap Datetimepicker. You can see the [minimal requirements here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

Few Important things to point :

- Always use the latest versions from all the links I have given below(previous versions have some problems apparently as I have investigated).
- You need `moment.js`(v2.11.2 as of now). [Get it from here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js)
- You need the latest `bootstrap-datetimepicker..min.js` and `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css`(v4.17.37 as of now). [Get it from here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37)

And most Important to note the order of the files included(use it in the same order I mentioned below) :

**JS files**

1. jquery.min.js
2. moment.min.js
3. bootstrap.min.js
4. bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

**CSS files**

1. bootstrap.min.css
2. bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css

This should get you working.

Comment: I done all taht you sad it looking better but something missing.

Comment: If you have everything in order including the CSS files, then its most probably the versions. Can you check

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should reference your js file. Surely, Others are not necessary

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Use js min files when you are going to deploy. Also I don't notice any css files here. Please add those before referring js files. You should have loaded bootstrap.css file.